# How to uppercase all input in elisp?

Tags: hooks, inputs

I want to create a mode which in certain states converts all input to uppercase, regardless of the caps-lock status. But I'm at a loss as to how to go for this, and I'm not sure it could even be done. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could create 26 key-bindings (your own major-mode, or your own minor-mode) and thus not have to worry about playing with any hooks.  Or, you could play with the `pre-command-hook` or `post-command-hook` if you don't want 26 key-bindings.

Comment: There is also the `post-self-insert-hook` if you prefer using that (for a custom uppercase function) instead of having 26 key-bindings.

Comment: You might want to look at [sqlup](https://github.com/Trevoke/sqlup-mode.el) for a similar minor mode. You have the benefit of your solution being even simpler! The author even [gave a presentation](https://blog.trevoke.net/sqlup-talk/#/slide-orgheadline1) about this, which might be useful as reference.

Answer (score 2):

You could do worse than look at GNU ELPA's `caps-lock` package.

Comment: I think the wording of your answer, while logically very clear, is confusing (but I'm not english native)

Comment: I will look into it. However I was hoping for an answer that didn't require external packages.

Comment: @Andrea IIUC this package provides a solution to your problem. Either you use it, or you decide you want to rewrite it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it by adding a buffer local `post-command-hook` and upcasing the previous word when the `self-insert-command` is executed and I am in the right state.

```
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'mymode-post-command-hook nil t)

(defun mymode-post-command-hook ()
  (when (and
         (eq this-command 'self-insert-command)
         (eq mymode-state 0))
    (upcase-word -1)))
```

I have tested this a bit and seems to work fine. It could probably be slimmer with the `post-self-insert-hook`. Thank you for all the suggestions.